# Deploying back-end with Zeit-now

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend, web-deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my back-end using Zeit:

`now` command

1. I have a MongoDB database (on mongoDB Atlas)
2. I saved my Connection string URL as a `secret` using:

   `now secrets add secret-name mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0-7c8ma.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
3. Within my code i defined my database as an environment variable:

   `const db = monk(process.env.DBName)`
4. then when deploying I used the command:

   `now -e DBName=@secret-name`
5. Expecting it to connect to my database on Atlas when it's deployed

But instead, when it gets deployed, the `.sh` URL i get from `now` is just a web page with my code written out. Any reason why it does this instead of displaying my database in json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `now.json` file was not configured correctly. Zeit now is automatically "assuming that my file was a static file instead of a `node.js` project" - CJ Coding Garden

```
{
    "name": "valorantlfgposts-db",
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "index.js",
        "use": "@now/node-server"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      { "src": "/.*", "dest": "/index.js" }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: what configuration change did you have to do, to resolve this? I am having the same problem